# Android WifiManager disconnect from a WifiSpot but never connects automatically again

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am using this code to disconnect from a Wifispot:

```
if(getActivity()!=null) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.disconnect();
}
```

WiFi disconnects and Settings show Wifi On, the wifi I was connected is shown as

**Saved, secured with WPA/WPA2**

That's perfect. The problem is that I get out of range and return into the range again of the WiFi, it doesn't "reconnect" automatically. Which code should I add to automatically reconnects WiFis disconnected by WifiManager?

Answer (score 2):

When you set up your wifi configuration.

add this :

```
   mWifiConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
```

for more information http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html

Hope this help!